# (Python3)Passing an object to an imported module function

Tags: python, object, module, discord.py

I am importing a module I created to a python file which I plan to run as main.

In the module, I have a function,

```
def coms(message, instRole):
```

where `instRole` is supposed to be an instance of a class

---

In my main python file, I have an object,

```
instRole = Role()
```

And I have a function:

```
def on_message(message):
    coms(message, instRole)
```

which I call on the next line:

```
on_message(m)
```

However, The function coms is never called. I have put in print statements in coms to make sure it is called, and it is not.

Thank you for your help ahead of time

Comment: Could you post the actual, complete code? This would help in identifying the issue. As well, post any error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to take advantage of [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) events, where your code would be executed whenever a message is seen by the bot, you have you define a *coroutine* (a function that uses the `async def` syntax) and use the `bot.event` decorator to register it with your bot.  Below is a basic example:

```
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from other_file import coms

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    instRole = get(message.server.roles, id="123")  # Get the role with its id
    await coms(message, instRole)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

If you want the coroutine in the other file to actually *do* something in discord, it's best to make that file a cog, which is a class that implements a specific functionality for a discord bot.

cog.py:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Cog():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    # Note no decorator
    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.coms(message, instRole)
    async def coms(self, message, role):
        ...  # use self.bot instead of bot

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Cog(bot))
```

main.py:

```
from discord.ext import commands 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

cogs = ['cog']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for cog in cogs:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(cog)
        except Exception:
            print('Failed to load cog {}\n{}'.format(extension, exc))

    bot.run('token')
```